# Get twitter-api url query in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter

I'm building a website with an area in the page displaying the tweets for a certain user.

I have somehow managed to find the latest tweets posted to a certain user using Twitter API querying method. But I have to get the list into a variable in my JavaScript code so that I can dynamically post into my website. Is there any method for doing so?

Apologies if the question is silly since I'm a fresh learner to JavaScript.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitter_user&count=50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
var twitter_api = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitter_user&count=50";

$.ajax({
   url: twitter_api,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(response){
     //here you do whatever you want with the response variable
   }
});
```